# Is there any possible way to show all the material name in datagridview, even though the other column is empty?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

In my inventory program there was 3 tables in my database.
1. Input
   Column(id,Material,Quantity)
2. Output 
   Column(id,Material,Quantity)
3. MaterialList (Table) Where I can input the names of materials
   Column(id,Material)

In my remaining Stocks form I want to show the Remaining Stocks of all MaterialList including the material that has no stocks.

For example:
From MaterialList       From Input and Output Quantity
Material list           Remaining Stocks
item1                         150
item2
item3
item4                         200

I tried this but there's no hope.

```
   conn.Open()
        conn = New MySqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=SOUTHEAST;database=reportingsystem"
        Dim searchquery As String = "select reportingsystem.rawmaterialswarehouseandrawmaterials.Rawmaterials, reportingsystem.rawmaterialswarehouseandrawmaterials.safetystocks, (Sum(reportingsystem.rawmaterialsinput.Quantity) - sum(reportingsystem.rawmaterialsoutput.Quantity)) as 'Remaining Stocks' from reportingsystem.rawmaterialsinput, reportingsystem.rawmaterialsoutput, reportingsystem.rawmaterialswarehouseandrawmaterials where reportingsystem.rawmaterialsinput.RawMaterial = reportingsystem.rawmaterialswarehouseandrawmaterials.Rawmaterials" ' JOIN reportingsystem.rawmaterialsinput.RawMaterial ON reportingsystem.rawmaterialswarehouseandrawmaterials.Rawmaterials = reportingsystem.rawmaterialsinput.RawMaterial ORDER BY reportingsystem.rawmaterialswarehouseandrawmaterials.Rawmaterials"
        'Select rawmaterialsinput.DeliveryDate as 'Delivery Date', rawmaterialswarehouseandrawmaterials.Rawmaterials, (sum(rawmaterialsinput.Quantity) - sum(rawmaterialsoutput.Quantity)) as 'Quantity' , rawmaterialswarehouseandrawmaterials.safetystocks from reportingsystem.rawmaterialsinput, reportingsystem.rawmaterialsoutput, reportingsystem.rawmaterialswarehouseandrawmaterials where rawmaterialsinput.RawMaterial = rawmaterialsoutput.RawMaterial
        '"Select rawmaterialswarehouseandrawmaterials.Rawmaterials as 'Raw Materials', rawmaterialswarehouseandrawmaterials.safetystocks as 'Safety Stock', (sum(rawmaterialsinput.Quantity) - sum(rawmaterialsoutput.Quantity)) as 'Remaining Stocks' where rawmaterialsinput.RawMaterial = rawmaterialswarehouseandrawmaterials.Rawmaterials FROM reportingsystem.rawmaterialswarehouseandrawmaterials, reportingsystem.rawmaterialsinput, reportingsystem.rawmaterialsoutput"
        'Select rawmaterialswarehouseandmaterials.Rawmaterials, (sum(rawmaterialsinput.Quantity) - sum(rawmaterialsoutput.Quantity)) as 'Remaining Stocks', rawmaterialswarehouseandrawmaterials.safetystocks FROM reportingsystem.rawmaterialswarehouseandrawmaterials, reportingsystem.rawmaterialsinput, reportingsystem.rawmaterialsoutput JOIN input ON rawmaterialsinput.RawMaterial = rawmaterialswarehouseandrawmaterials.Rawmaterials
        Dim commander As New MySqlCommand(searchquery, conn)
        Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(commander)

        monitoringdata.Clear()

        adapter.Fill(monitoringdata)

        MonitoringDGV.DataSource = monitoringdata

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In MonitoringDGV.Rows
            Dim quantity As Integer = Val(row.Cells(1).Value)
            Dim safetystocks As Integer = Val(row.Cells(2).Value)
            If safetystocks < quantity Then
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red

            ElseIf safetystocks < (quantity * 1.2) Then

                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green


            ElseIf safetystocks > (quantity * 1.2) Then
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green

            End If
        Next
        conn.Close()
```

What I really need is show all of the Material Name in column 1 and show the remaining stocks in column 2.

Example:

Material        Remaining Stocks
Item1                   1
Item2                   4
Item3
Item4
Item5                   18
Item6                   30
Item7

Comment: I assume it’s not really a vb.net problem but a database query issue, you need to use outer join if there are no rows in the joined table and you want the results anyway. So look that up

Comment: Oh it's okay. I fix my problem. BTW. Thanks for your time